# Weird suggested edit with no context

Tags: discussion, support

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/30251 and the next one offer no context on what the original post was.  Is this as its meant to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [discharge](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discharge) is being used on questions, but nobody yet took the effort of writing a tag-wiki (and tag wiki excerpt). So the first one who proposes content for the tag wiki basically changes the empty text to a new text. Also notice that you often get two almost similar edits, but if you watch closely one is for the wiki and the other one for the wiki-excerpt.

My personal opinion is that any reasonable text for a tag wiki is better than an empty one, so I am usually pretty easy on approving initial proposed text. When necessary it can be improved and I think it the threshold for improving an existing tag wiki is easier taken than the threshold for coming up with a completely new text.

Comment: Got it.  Never saw a tag-wiki review before.  Guess its a new priv.

Comment: @ScottSeidman, it kicks in at 5k.